# Save chartkick chart as image or in pdf using python, flask and pisa/ xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, pdf, flask, pisa, pygal

My app is in python using the flask framework. I have a chart that I've generated with chartlink. I'd like to include it on a pdf that I'm outputting with pisa. Is this possible? Is there some way to save the chartkick chart as an image? Or should I look into another chart-generating option like pygal or matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [chartkick documentation](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js/tree/download#download-charts) you can give users the option to download an image of the chart.

You will have to include canvg before chartkick.js.

Another option would be to generate the image on a [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) instance and save the screenshot/image.