# Convert Chartkick graph to Image serverside in rails 4 app

Tags: google-visualization, chartkick

How do you convert Chartkick (using google charts) graphs to image at server side in rails 4 app?

Answer (score 0):

This post might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027847/2016383

It suggests to render a chart and save it to an image by using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and its [Screen Capture ability](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).